# Angular: Selectively compile templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I know that `ng-non-bindable` allows a given element and its children to be not compiled as a template.  It seems it was designed to be peppered throughout a template as needed.  Is there a way to tell Angular to not process a given element, BUT to "poke holes" into that and allow selected child elements to be processed?  For example, I'd love to be able to do something like this:

```
<div ng-non-bindable>
    <div>{{2+2}}</div>
    <div ng-bindable>{{2+2}}</div>
</div>
```

And have it output:

> {{2+2}}
>
> 4

I understand that `ng-non-bindable` wouldn't even allow `ng-bindable` to be processed, even if it existed.  But does anything exist to allow an approach to templates like I've expressed?

To be more thorough, my ideal solution would not process anything Angular until if found the `ng-bindable`, not just the curly brace expressions.  For example:

```
<div ng-non-bindable>
    <div ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]">{{n+2}}</div>
    <div ng-bindable ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]">{{n+2}}</div>
</div>
```

would result in:

> {{n+2}}
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Custom `nonBindable` directive

You will not be able to use `ngNonBindable` (well, you could decorate it) like this due to how directive is configured. However it's pretty easy to write custom directive with this behavior:

```
app.directive('nonBindable', function($compile) {
    return {
        terminal: true, 
        priority: 999,
        compile: function(tElement) {
            return function(scope) {
                var bindable = tElement[0].querySelectorAll('[bindable]');
                [].forEach.call(bindable, function(el) {
                    $compile(el)(scope);
                });    
            };
        }
    };
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<div non-bindable>
    <div>{{2+2}}</div>
    <div bindable>{{2+2}}</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div non-bindable>
    <div ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]">{{n+2}}</div>
    <div bindable ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]">{{n+2}}</div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/NEDP4WkBN4TlXdXKo8WI?p=preview

#### Decorate `ngNonBindable`

You can decorate original `ngNonBindable` directive like this:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('ngNonBindableDirective', function($delegate, $compile) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        directive.compile = function(tElement) {
            return function(scope) {
                var bindable = tElement[0].querySelectorAll('[bindable]');
                [].forEach.call(bindable, function(el) {
                    $compile(el)(scope);
                });
            };
        };
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

and use it this way:

```
<div ng-non-bindable>
    <div>{{2+2}}</div>
    <div bindable>{{2+2}}</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div ng-non-bindable>
    <div ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]">{{n+2}}</div>
    <div bindable ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3]">{{n+2}}</div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/HVczVkkQR88hC7191ep0?p=preview