# AngularJS ngTouch and ngSwipe throw error "TypeError: element.on is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, debugging, event-handling, onload, angularjs-ng-touch

I am using angular 1.4.0 and jQuery v1.11.1.

I am trying to use ngTouch/ngSwipe. Both will not stop throwing the error "TypeError: element.on is not a function" on app loading (inside the bind-function). Sadly I can't reproduce this error in a plunkr, anyhow ngSwipe runs into that issue, when:

```
    bind: function(element, eventHandlers, pointerTypes) {
       ...
    pointerTypes = pointerTypes || ['mouse', 'touch'];
    element.on(getEvents(pointerTypes, 'start'), function(event) {... <-- error here
```

I don't think this is too much an issue with my other code, but that I'm missing some kind of dependency. Anyone got an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$on` method is part of the `angular.element` object, whereas the `on` method is part of the jQuery object. The `element` in question is a DOM object, which has no such method. The closest equivalent would be:

```
element.addEventListener(getEvents(pointerTypes, 'start'), function(event){} )
```

or:

```
$(element).on(getEvents(pointerTypes, 'start'), function(event){} )
```

**References**

- [Angular Docs: type $rootScope.Scope: $on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)
- [Angular Docs: $compile service: usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage)
- [.on() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [AngularJS standard directive priority list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074044/1113772)
- [Angular: Selectively compile templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393359/1113772)